# ping: unknown host in Centos 6.6

Tags: dns, centos, ping

It's OK to ping IP address.
[picture about ping and cat /etc/resolve.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5X8r.png)

I can ping 8.8.8.8, so the DNS server is OK to reach, and /etc/resolv.conf edited correctly. But I just can't ping domain. I've tried shutdown firewall but failed. Too strange, I used `service iptables stop` and iptables was still there.

Two problems:
1. unknown host
2. stop iptables failed.

Anyone can tell me how to fix these?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by accident and I don't know if it's copyable, but I need to write it down.

```
 1. I set /etc/hosts to run command `yum install bind-utils`.
 2. then, I run command `dig +trace www.baidu.com` to find out why ping fail.
```

then, miracle happens. I can ping domain again. The problem solved magically just as it occurred.